# What is the deal with the "invisible schema" pg_catalog?

Tags: postgresql

If I run this query:

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename, indexname, indexdef FROM pg_indexes ORDER BY schemaname ASC, tablename ASC, indexname ASC;
```

It returns a ton of records for the nonexistent schema "pg_catalog". It's not a schema in my database. I assume it's some kind of internal, "secret" schema, but I find no mention of it in the PG manual when I searched for it before asking.

Answer (score 3):

> It's not a schema in my database.

Yes, it is. And it's neither "invisible" nor undocumented:

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG)

> In addition to public and user-created schemas, each database contains a pg_catalog schema, which contains the system tables and all the built-in data types, functions, and operators. pg_catalog is always effectively part of the search path.

All views and tables in the `pg_catalog` schema are documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs-overview.html)